# CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found with another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

First of all I want to apologize for my English, =). I am making a web application but when redirecting program flow to another controllador I get this error: "404 Page Not Found". The classes and files are capitalized as I have read in other posts and that might not be. Thanks in advance.

This is the main controller (Auth Controller) that calls to "Activity" with "redirect":

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    redirect('auth/login');
}

public function login() {

    if (!$this->input->post())
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/main_template', array(
            'title' => 'Login',
            'header' => $this->load->view('templates/header', null, TRUE),
            'content' => $this->load->view('pages/login', null, TRUE),
            'footer' => $this->load->view('templates/footer', null, TRUE)
        ));
        return;
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('useremail', 'Useremail', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); // trim: quita espacios; required: campo requerido; xss_clean: elimina posibles inyecciones sql; callback_user_auth: otras funciones y llamadas, en este caso llamada a funciónq que autentifica al usuario
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_user_auth'); // |callback_user_auth
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // LOGIN VIEW (home)
        $this->load->view('templates/main_template', array(
            'title' => 'Login',
            'header' => $this->load->view('templates/header', null, TRUE),
            'content' => $this->load->view('pages/login', null, TRUE),
            'footer' => $this->load->view('templates/footer', null, TRUE)
        ));;

    } else {

        redirect('activity/list_actividades');
    }
} 

public function user_auth($password) { 
    $useremail = $this->input->post('useremail');
    $user = $this->User_model->authenticate($useremail, $password);

    if ($user)
    {
        // valid user, set session data
        $this->session->logged_in = array(
            'useremail' => $user->email,
            'username' => $user->name,
            'group' => $user->group // CAMBIO EN LA BASE DE DATOS 
        ); // GROUP POR ADMIN. DEPENDIENDO DEL GRUPO SE TIENEN UNOS PERMISOS U OTROS


        return TRUE;
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('user_auth', 'Invalid username or password');

    return FALSE;
}

public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    redirect('auth/login');
}
```

Activity Controller:

```
class Activity extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // check for the session here... in theory
}

public function index() {
    redirect('auth/login');
}

public function list_actividades () {

    $this->load->model('Activity_model');
    $data['actividades'] = $this->Activity_model->getAll();
    $data['grupo_usuario'] = $this->session->logged_in['group'];

    $this->load->view('templates/main_template', array(
        'title' => 'Lista de Actividades',
        'header' => $this->load->view('templates/header', null, TRUE),
        'content' => $this->load->view('templates/lista_actividades', $data, TRUE),
        'footer' => $this->load->view('templates/footer', null, TRUE)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Have you configured your application/config/config.php and routes.php files properly and added a .htaccess file as recommended in CI Docs? because the way you are using redirect urls will only work if you do the above steps properly.

Comment: I have tried to do it, but I don't know if I have done well

Comment: The first controller is working with the setup, and I have other controller than run perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it finally was that when you are using authorization hook you have to register the authorized addresses in the acl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a */ in your function list_actividades
it might be possible that CodeIgniter ignores the error, but couldn't read the class because of it, resulting in a 404